Repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes in "Ref. [citation-number]" style
I found @moewe answer here incredibly helpful and elegant. It provides a very smooth solution for considering repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes.
However, there are specific situations in a text where one would like to use citations not as superscript but rather as "Ref [citation-number]" style, e.g., sometimes, depending on how the phrase is constructed, one would like to do:
"As shown in Ref. [1] ..."
How could one possibly create another command equivalent to \myfootcite, e.g. \myfootcitenumber command so that
As shown in Ref. [\myfootcitenumber]...

would produce something like
"As shown in Ref. [1] ..."

In other words, the expected beaviour would be:
This or that approach has been investigated in the past.1
However, as shown in Ref. [2], such an approach lacks enough robustness.

References
...

where 1 appears as superscript
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-note]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{myfootcite}}
  {}
  {}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\usebibmacro{myfootcite:note}}
    {\mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcite:note}{\footref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
This or that approach has been investigated in the past.\myfootcite{cicero}
However, as shown in Ref. [\myfootcitenum{knuth:ct:a}], such an approach lacks enough robustness.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Taking some ideas from Auto-insert "Ref." word before citation and copying the suggested approach from biblatex repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes I suggest you try
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-note]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{myfootcite}}
  {}
  {}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\footref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
    {\mkbibfootnote{%
       \usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}}

\NewBibliographyString{reference}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  reference = {ref\adddot},
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcitenum}[\bibsentence\bibstring{reference}\addnbspace\mkbibbrackets]
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{myfootcitenum}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcitenum}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
    {\stepcounter{footnote}%
     \mkbibfootnotetext{%
       \usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}%
     \hyperref[cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}]{\thefootnote}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First citation.\myfootcite{cicero}
First citation.\myfootcite{knuth:ct:a}
Lorem\footnote{ipsum} dolor\myfootcite{wilde} sit\footnote{amet} and something\myfootcite{wilde}
Second citation.\myfootcite{cicero}

\myfootcitenum{cicero}

\myfootcitenum{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Personally, I prefer to rewrite my text so that the citation label is never part of the sentence, since I dislike constructions like "as shown in [1]" especially when used with other citation styles like author-year.

Many thanks, that worked

You can't use a citation command that has yet to be defined, such as the \myfootcitenum one. You have to create it.
I suggest to change the myfootcite macro again, as it will be shared by both the existing citation command that displays the superscript number and the new citation command you are defining.
\newbibmacro*{myfootcite}{%
    \mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
    \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}

Replace the one you have with this one. This will work every time both citation commands are used with the same entry for the first time, regardless of which command is used first.
Then create the myfootcite:superscript macro. It will be used for subsequent citations made with the \myfootcite command and will print the corresponding footnote number as a superscript.
\newbibmacro*{myfootcite:superscript}{%
    \footref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}

Next, modify the \myfootcite citation command. This customisation performs the \ifciteseen check at the level of the citation command itself, duplicating the macros and activating each one based on the result of the boolean check. Therefore, the meaning of the \myfootcite citation command remains unchanged.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifciteseen%
        {\usebibmacro{myfootcite:superscript}}%
        {\usebibmacro{myfootcite}}}
    {\textsuperscript{\multicitedelim}}
    {}

I included the \multicitedelim command to improve multiple footnotes when you cite two or more sources together. Each source will have its own footnote mark and its own footnote and there will be a separator between them, which will appear as superscript, just like the marks.
What you are looking for is primarily located in this new macro. I already included the number within square brackets. This macro references the same number as the footnote corresponding to the first citation of the entry.
\newbibmacro*{myfootcite:num}{%
    \printtext[brackets]{%
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

Here, finally, is the myfootcitenum citation command you're looking for. Once again, I included the check for whether the work has been cited before directly within the citation command itself.
If the work has not been cited previously, I call the macro that was used in the previous citation command (\myfootcite), namely the myfootcite one. Otherwise, the newly created macro myfootcite:num will be activated.
I encountered difficulties with the delimiter used between multiple entries within a single \myfootcitenum citation command. For now, I implemented a short horizontal space, as I haven't yet determined how to control the superscript formatting of the \multicitedelim command depending on whether it precedes a first citation or a previously cited work.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcitenum}
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifciteseen%
        {\usebibmacro{myfootcite:num}}%
        {\usebibmacro{myfootcite}}}
    {\hspace{0.5em}}
    {}

Just a note. The \myfootcite citation command «(obviously) cannot deal with pre- or postnotes» macros, as Moewe indicated in the answer you referred and which formed the basis of this question. In my opinion, the new \myfootcitenum citation command could potentially be compatible with these macros. If you would like to test it, here is a reformulated version incorporating these two macros: so, try to change the new myfootcite:num macro and myfootcitenum citation command, to move the brackets format to the latter and to consider the prenote and postnote macro.
\newbibmacro*{myfootcite:num}{%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext{%
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
    
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcitenum}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifciteseen%
        {\usebibmacro{myfootcite:num}}%
        {\usebibmacro{myfootcite}}}
    {\hspace{0.5em}}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


Thanks, but I've put the pieces together but does not produce the expected behaviour (see updated post)
